# Nginx url rewrite uppercase to lowercase

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, lowercase

is there a way to only translate the requested url to lowercase and not things like image sources or links etc?

I tried this approach but it also translates the image sources to lowercase so they wont work anymore.

[How i can translate uppercase to lowercase letters in a rewrite rule in nginx web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666003/how-i-can-translate-uppercase-to-lowercase-letters-in-a-rewrite-rule-in-nginx-we/11170826#11170826)

Thanks!