# NGINX $request_uri vs $uri

Tags: nginx, uri

How do you determine when to use `$request_uri` vs `$uri`?

According to NGINX documentation, `$request_uri` is the original request (for example, `/foo/bar.php?arg=baz` includes arguments and can't be modified) but `$uri` refers to the altered URI.

If the URI doesn't change, does $uri = $request_uri?

Would it be incorrect or better or worse to use:

```
map $uri $new_uri {
  # do something
}
```

vs

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
  # do something
}
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

`$uri` is not equivalent to `$request_uri`.

The `$uri` variable is set to the URI that `nginx` is **currently processing** - but it is also subject to normalisation, including:

- Removal of the `?` and query string
- Consecutive `/` characters are replace by a single `/`
- URL encoded characters are decoded

The value of `$request_uri` is always the original URI and is not subject to any of the above normalisations.

Most of the time you would use `$uri`, because it is normalised. Using `$request_uri` in the wrong place can cause URL encoded characters to become doubly encoded.

Use `$request_uri` in a `map` directive, if you need to match the URI and its query string.

Comment: Also, using `$uri` accidentally in `proxy_pass` directives opens you up to http header injection vulnerabilities. Always use `$request_uri` in proxy_pass.

Comment: @fotinakis, could you give an example of such injection? I can't really imagine a single scenario.

Comment: @VictorSchröder say `/static/*` is proxy_pass'd to a different destination, but accidentally uses `$uri` instead of `$request_uri`. You could navigate to `/static/X%20HTTP/1.1%0d%0aHost:hijacked-host-header%0d%0a%0d%0a` and the `Host:hijacked-host-header` header will get injected.

Comment: @fotinakis, so this would trigger a secondary request to the proxied host with a manipulated `Host` header? Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @fotinakis can you fix this by setting `proxy_pass_request_headers off;`

Answer (score 21):

Another difference about `$uri` and `$request_uri` in `proxy_cache_key` is  `$request_uri` will include `anchor tags part`, but `$uri$is_args$args` will ignore it

Do a curl operation : `curl -I static.io/hello.htm?id=1#/favor/goods` :

```
proxy_cache_key $scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args; => Cache KEY: http://static.io/hello.htm?id=1
proxy_cache_key $scheme://$host$request_uri; => Cache KEY: http://static.io/hello.htm?id=1#/favor/goods
```

---

Nginx Document: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri

- `$request_uri` : full original request URI (with arguments)
- `$uri`:
  current URI in request, normalized The value of $uri may change
  during request processing, e.g. when doing internal redirects, or
  when using index files.

Proxy Cache key:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key

Comment: No browser I know of sends the fragment identifier to the server: faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1808.html 2.4.1.  Parsing the Fragment Identifier

Comment: Interesting, I haven't tested it yet but these guys say exactly the opposite, that **request_uri** does *not* include anchors: https://www.webhosting24.com/understanding-nginx-request_uri/

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/901331/nginx-redirect-rule-with-a-anchor-tag
says:
"nginx never receives the part after # in the HTTP request, it is purely a HTTP client (browser) side concept.

This means that the following regexp will match both /view-price-range.php#mytag and /view-price-range.php#mytag"