# nginx mapping list of urls from a file

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

hey there I have around 5k~ of urls to be redirected. I am trying to apply the logic defined in this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354142/nginx-how-to-mass-permanent-redirect-from-a-given-list)
,however, I am getting an error after testing the config file which is;

```
2019/10/07 10:08:33 [emerg] 386#386: unknown "old_uri" variable
nginx: [emerg] unknown "old_uri" variable
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Here are the very basic files from a hello-world nginx example I am dealing with.

***/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf***

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirects.map;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    if ($new_uri) {
    rewrite ^ $new_uri permanent;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

***redirects.map***

```
map $old_uri $new_uri {
    default "";
    /about.html /about-us;
    /careers.html /awesome-careers;
}
```

***/etc/nginx/nginx.conf***

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*;
}
```

Thanks for helping! Really appreciated

Comment: There is no variable called `$old_uri`. Do you mean `$request_uri`?

Comment: Lol I thought we define urls and nginx just resolve them. thanks a lot @RichardSmith it worked. Can you add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `map` the variable `$old_uri` does not exists, you should be using `$request_uri` or `$uri` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708361/nginx-request-uri-vs-uri/48709976#48709976) for the difference.

In the `if` block, use your `rewrite` statement if you want the original query string appended to the new URI.

Otherwise, use `return 301 $new_uri;` if you want the original query string discarded.

Comment: thanks a lot! All the urls are actually static urls without no any query parameters. So, in this case I should use `return 301 $new_uri;` right?

Comment: The `rewrite` statement will work, but is overkill. The `return` statement is more efficient.