# Properly using $uri for nginx auth mapping

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'd like to make an easy but flexible way (without headers, but also without basicauth) to authorize users to a server resource. Borrowing from another method (that did use headers), I thought it would be relatively trivial to check the URI through auth_request:

```
include api_keys.conf

server {
    # ...
    
    location = /_validate_apikey {
        internal;

        if ($uri = "") {
            return 401; # Unauthorized
        }
        if ($api_client_name = "") {
            return 403; # Forbidden
        }

        return 204; # OK (no content)
    }

    location ^~ / {
        auth_request /_validate_apikey;
        # ...
    }
```

```
# api_keys.conf
map $uri $api_client_name {
    "ZXr8ok2ERCtryQJdJ2GD" "User A";
    "MnCp5rcZsbocLTk2vmNW" "User B";

    default "";
}
```

After turning on debug logging, I noticed that `$uri` contained the leading slash, so I tried adding that, as well as a trailing `?` (the logs contained both), but neither one seems to work.

Is trying to use URIs in this manner a fool's errand, or do I have something easily-fixable in my configuration?

Comment: The value of `$uri` includes a leading `/`, but does not include the `?`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708361/nginx-request-uri-vs-uri/48709976#48709976)

Comment: Ah! This seems to be the issue - can you add this as an answer so I can properly upvote and close? Thanks so much @RichardSmith